# Advanced export profile in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I cant find any documentation on this, I dont even know if its possible.
I need to export some products, I already have the profile, because this export is for a competitive site like nextag.com or pricegrabber.com we want to export only a few products and not the 3000 we have.

I could create a boolean attribute called Export.

The problem is how can I put in the profile to export only products that export is set to yes?

This is the code that it generates:

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[5]]></var>
    <var name="filter/type"><![CDATA[simple]]></var>
    <var name="filter/price/from"><![CDATA[90]]></var>
    <var name="filter/price/to"><![CDATA[6000]]></var>
    <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[5]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[MPN/UPC]]></map>
        <map name="brand"><![CDATA[Manufacturer]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[Product Name]]></map>
        <map name="product_link"><![CDATA[product_link]]></map>
        <map name="condition"><![CDATA[Product Condition]]></map>
        <map name="price"><![CDATA[Selling Price]]></map>
        <map name="shipping_costs"><![CDATA[Shipping costs]]></map>
        <map name="weight_box1"><![CDATA[Weight]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[nextagfeed.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

Thank

Comment: Hi, I have a question about the terms used in this profile code. Specifically, `sku` and `MPN/UPC`. Which are these in the Magento admin site? Are they Attribute Code and Attribute Label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the export filter to your actions xml

```
<var name="filter/export"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
```

Something like

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[5]]></var>
    <var name="filter/type"><![CDATA[simple]]></var>
    <var name="filter/price/from"><![CDATA[90]]></var>
    <var name="filter/price/to"><![CDATA[6000]]></var>
    <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="filter/export"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[5]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[MPN/UPC]]></map>
        <map name="brand"><![CDATA[Manufacturer]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[Product Name]]></map>
        <map name="product_link"><![CDATA[product_link]]></map>
        <map name="condition"><![CDATA[Product Condition]]></map>
        <map name="price"><![CDATA[Selling Price]]></map>
        <map name="shipping_costs"><![CDATA[Shipping costs]]></map>
        <map name="weight_box1"><![CDATA[Weight]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[nextagfeed.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

That is telling magento to filter the product collection by price status and the export attribute, because export is boolean you need set the corresponding boolean  value in this case 1 for true.

Now if this doesn't work maybe it would be easier adding your product Parser and using advanced imports. Let me know how it goes.

Ok, now we know that definitively doesn't work but lets look why it doesn't work. The reason is we are missing that filter on our adapter open

```
app/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php
```

look for the load function around line 99:

```
public function load()
{
    $attrFilterArray = array();
    $attrFilterArray ['name']           = 'like';
    $attrFilterArray ['sku']            = 'startsWith';
    $attrFilterArray ['type']           = 'eq';
    $attrFilterArray ['attribute_set']  = 'eq';
    $attrFilterArray ['visibility']     = 'eq';
    $attrFilterArray ['status']         = 'eq';
    $attrFilterArray ['price']          = 'fromTo';
    $attrFilterArray ['qty']            = 'fromTo';
    $attrFilterArray ['store_id']       = 'eq';

    $attrToDb = array(
        'type'          => 'type_id',
        'attribute_set' => 'attribute_set_id'
    );
```

And just below store id add your new filter

```
 $attrFilterArray ['is_imported']     = 'eq';
```

Cheers

Comment: it didnt work, but I was check, and the attribute is not boolean but a dropdown, so I changed it to this?  <map name="is_exported"><![CDATA[is_imported]]></map>.  and it still exports everything

Comment: wait a minute, actions.xml? that file does not exist in my entire magento installation, the customization you said I put in the advanced profile editor.

Comment: Lol I didn't said actions.xml I meant Profile Actions xml and if your property is called is_exported then it should be <var name="filter/is_exported"><![CDATA[is_imported]]></var> inside the actions

Comment: I deleted the comment, I didnt do it well, I was in a bit hurry, however I double checked and now I used the correct attribute code, but still does not work. <var name="filter/is_import"><![CDATA[Yes]]></var>?

Comment: Luis, Why are you using Yes? what is the actual attribute code ? and values

Comment: the attribute code = "is_import", its a dropdown attribute which possible values are Yes and No.   I made a mistake in the original post, thats why I put Yes in the comment. Am I confused?

Comment: Yes, try placing the following <var name="filter/is_import"><![CDATA[1]]></var>

Comment: same result :) it exports everything.

Comment: @LuisEValencia, please state a bit clearly, Does the solution works for you? although you have accepted the answer...but your very last comment is quite confusing